# oracle sql to retrieve followup dates from a preceding date

Tags: oracle, lead

```
CREATE TABLE tst_tbl
(
   id                 NUMBER,
   last_name          VARCHAR2 (50),
   first_name         VARCHAR2 (50),
   dob                DATE,
   register_dt        DATE,
   register_loc       VARCHAR2 (50),
   visit_dt           DATE,
   visit_loc          VARCHAR2 (50),
   visit_comments   VARCHAR2 (30)
);


INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('09/05/2017' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,'NEW YORK',  to_date('02/26/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('09/05/2017' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,'NEW YORK',  to_date('2/12/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('09/05/2017' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,'NEW YORK',  to_date('11/6/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('09/05/2017' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,'NEW YORK',  to_date('10/23/2017','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('09/05/2017' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,'NEW YORK',  to_date('3/27/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('09/05/2017' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,'NEW YORK',  to_date('3/19/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('09/05/2017' ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,'NEW YORK',  to_date('9/11/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('2/7/2018'   ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,  'NEW YORK',to_date('11/6/2017 ','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('2/7/2018'   ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,  'NEW YORK',to_date('3/19/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('2/7/2018'   ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,  'NEW YORK',to_date('9/11/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('2/7/2018'   ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,  'NEW YORK',to_date('3/27/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('2/7/2018'   ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,  'NEW YORK',to_date('2/26/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('2/7/2018'   ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,  'NEW YORK',to_date('10/23/2017','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'NEW JERSEY', '');
INSERT INTO tst_tbl VALUES(1234, 'John', 'Smith', to_date('12/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY') , to_date('2/7/2018'   ,'MM/DD/YYYY')   ,  'NEW YORK',to_date('2/12/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'NEW JERSEY', '');
COMMIT;
```

I want immediate visit information(visit_dt, visit_loc, ..) following a register date.

eg:

```
1234, John, Smith, 12/01/1980, 09/05/2017,  NEW YORK, 9/11/2017, NEW JERSEY
1234, John, Smith, 12/01/1980, 2/7/2018,  NEW YORK, 2/12/2018, NEW JERSEY
```

I tried with the below logic to sort the register dates and visit dates and then use lead to retrieve the following date and filter only for register dates. But, i am unable to add other fields as shown above..

```
 SELECT 
      dt, vst_type, register_dt, vst_dt
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        id, dt, vst_type, 
        dt AS register_dt,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER 
            ( 
              PARTITION BY id, dt ORDER BY
                CASE 
                  WHEN vst_type = 'REGISTER_DT' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
            )
        AS vst_dt_rnum,
        LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS vst_dt
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT id, register_dt AS dt, 'REGISTER_DT' vst_type FROM tst_tbl
        UNION
        SELECT id, visit_dt AS dt, 'VISIT_DT' vst_type FROM tst_tbl
      )
    )
    WHERE vst_dt_rnum = 1 AND vst_type = 'REGISTER_DT'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and assuming that the ID is a unique identifier, you want to group the rows by (ID, REGISTER_DT) and from each group to keep just the rows with VISIT_DT >= REGISTER_DT, and then from each group select the earliest (oldest) row by VISIT_DT. If so, something like this should work:

```
select (columns you want)
from   (
         select t.* 
              , row_number() over (partition by id, register_dt
                                   order by visit_dt) as rn
         from   tst_tbl t
         where  visit_dt >= register_dt
       )
where  rn = 1
;
```

Comment: thanks a million mathguy, this is the one i am looking for. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're overcomplicating things. Here's a way you can add an indicator if the visit date follows the register date by <30 days. If there's some reason this doesn't work for you, please edit your question and add more data (e.g. what should the output look like?)

```
select r.*, 
    case when (floor(visit_dt - register_dt) between 0 and 29) 
         then 'Y' else 'N' 
         end as less_than_30_days
from tst_tbl r;
```

But that's based on your sample output. Based on your query, it looks like you're trying to look for all visits which have *any* register date within the past 30 days (for that ID). If you'd prefer that instead, here's a simpler way to do it.

```
select v.*,
    (select nvl(max('Y'),'N')
      from tst_tbl r
      where r.id = v.id
        and (floor(v.visit_dt - r.register_dt) between 0 and 29))
      as reg_within_30_days
from tst_tbl v;
```

Comment: thanks for your response kfinity, i have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select id, last_name, first_name, dob, register_dt, register_loc,
visit_dt
From (
  Select r.id, r.last_name, r.first_name, r.dob, r.register_dt, r.register_loc,
r.visit_dt, r.visit_loc, row_number() over (partition by r.register_dt order by r.visit_dt) r
From tst_tbl r
where register_dt < visit_dt
) x
Where x.r = 1
```